# the closest prime number function

Tags: c++, c++17

i have a problem i can't create a loop
`while(!isPrimeNumber(x))`

so i have written a function `isPrimeNumber()`;

```
bool isPrimeNumber(int x)
{
    if (x < 0) x = 0;
    int wyznacznik = 0;
    for (int i = x - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            wyznacznik++;
        }
        
    }
    if (wyznacznik == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and it works, it checks if number is prime or not but the function `theClosestPrimeNumber` is not working and the code is

```
int theClosestPrimeNumber(int x) {
    int k = x;
    int n = x;
    int a = x;
    int x1 = x;
    if (isPrimeNumber(x)) {
        return x;
    } 
    if (!isPrimeNumber(x)) {
        while (!isPrimeNumber(x)) {
            x++;
        }
        k = x;
        while (!isPrimeNumber(n)) {
            n--;
        }
        a = n;
        if (x1-a > k - x1) {
            return a;
        }
        if (x1 - a <= k - x1) {
            return k;
        }
    
    }
}
```

I would want this function `theClosestPrimeNumber` start working

Comment: what is the meaning of "not working" ?

Comment: its much simpler to compute all prime numbers until you find a prime number that is larger than `x`. The result is then either this last prime number or the previous one. You are currently checking many numbers for being prime multiple times, while a sieve would be simpler and more efficient

Comment: This `isPrimeNumber()` function will return false for all numbers>1.

Comment: It would be way more readable when you name your variables `closestPrimeBelow` and `closestPrimeAbove` or so instead of `n`, `x`, `k`, `x1`, `a`.

Comment: I believe that you either haven't actually tested `isPrimeNumber` with any prime numbers, or retyped it for this question and introduced an error.

Comment: *i have written a function isPrimeNumber and it works* This is not correct, for example `isPrimeNumber(2)` returns `false`.

Comment: You could decrease your isPrimeNumber’s function complexity by checking divisors from 2 to sqrt(n) only

Comment: @Alvov1 I second the tip about square root, but I'd recommend to stay in integer domain, i.e. compare `n` against `i*i`.

Comment: Look at the conditions in the final conditionals and think about whether you really are returning the *closest* number.

Comment: Note that 1 is not prime number and 0 is not prime number.

Answer (score 0):

Programming will be easier, if you use meaningful variable names and especially if you write comments. Best, if you write the comments, before you start coding.

Then, the task it not that easy, because you need to take the boundary values into account. So, the lowest and highest possible prime number.

Your approach with using delta values was a good idea.

The implementation should be improved.

Please look at the code below and use it, to get an understanding of what I explained and to derive your own solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>

// Simple prime checker
constexpr bool isPrime(const unsigned int number) noexcept {
    // Even numbers or numbers < 2 or not prime
    if (number == 2) return true;
    if (number % 2 == 0 or number < 2) return false;

    // Divide by all other potential numbers
    for (unsigned long long int i{ 3 }; i * i < number; ++i)
        if (number % i == 0) return false;

    // Number must be prime
    return true;
}


// The following will be done during compile time
// Lower prime boundary 
constexpr unsigned int lowestPrimeNumber{ 2 };

// Also the following function will be done during compile time
// Find the biggest prime taht this data type can hold
constexpr unsigned int getUpperBoundary() noexcept {

    // This will stop latest at 2, because 2 is a prime. But of course it will stop eralier
    for (unsigned int upperValue{ std::numeric_limits<decltype(upperValue)>::max() };; --upperValue) 
        if (isPrime(upperValue)) return upperValue;
}
// Also this will be a compile time constant
// Upper prime boundary
constexpr unsigned int highestPrimeNumber = getUpperBoundary();


// Now calculate the closest prime number for a given number
unsigned int closestPrimeNumber(const unsigned int number) {

    // Trivial case: If the number is prime, then return it immediately
    if (isPrime(number)) return number;

    // None trivial case. Search both the next upper and lower prime
    // Here we will later store the lower prime number, if it exists
    unsigned int lowerValue{ };
    // This flag will indicate that we found a lower prime
    bool lowerPrimeFound{};

    // Search next lower prime number
    if (number > lowestPrimeNumber)
    // Do this in a loop
    for (lowerValue = number - 1; lowerValue >= lowestPrimeNumber; --lowerValue)

        if (isPrime(lowerValue)) {
            // When we have found a prime, then stop the loop
            lowerPrimeFound = true;
            break;
        }


    // Here we will later store the upper prime number, if it exists
    unsigned int upperValue{};
    // This flag will indicate that we found an upper prime
    bool upperPrimeFound{};

    // Search next upper prime number
    if (number < highestPrimeNumber)

    // Do this in a loop
    for(upperValue = number + 1; upperValue <= highestPrimeNumber; ++upperValue)
        if (isPrime(upperValue)) {

            // When we have found a prime, then stop the loop
            upperPrimeFound = true;
            break;
        }

    // Return the result. Depending on what we found
    if (upperPrimeFound and lowerPrimeFound)

        // Check, if upper or lower number is closer. Select lower, if distance is same
        if ((number - lowerValue) <= (upperValue - number))
            return lowerValue;
        else
            return upperValue;
    else if (upperPrimeFound)
        return upperValue;
    else if (lowerPrimeFound)
        return lowerValue;
    else {
        std::cerr << "\nError: No value found\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

// Simple test program
int main() {

    // Check for the first x numbers
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {

        // Show result
        std::cout << "Number: " << (isPrime(i)? '*':' ') 
            << std::left << std::setw(std::numeric_limits<decltype(i)>::digits) << i
            << " Closest Prime: " << closestPrimeNumber(i) << '\n';
    }
}
```